# How to design database tables for dynamic forms (User defined fields)

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

Single value such as Text, Number, Decimal, is not hard to do, but what about radio options? checkboxes?

---

Single value UDF

```
FORM
- Id
- AttributeName
- DataTypeId

FORMVALUE
- Id
- FormId
- UserId (user that entered the value)
- Value

DATATYPE
- Id
- DataTypeName
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would use "atrributes" just for input and move it to normalized table.

Lets do reaserach first:

1. ComboBox - State (0/1)

   CREATE TABLE CHECKBOX(
      cb_id,
      cb_label,
      cb_state bit --0 no 1 yes)
2. RadioButton - Group with checked state.
   Hmm....

   ```
   CREATE TABLE RadioGroup (
   rg_id int primary increment etc,
   rg_name,
   rg_selectedindex)
   Create table RadioVariants
   (rv_id,
   rv_rd_id,
   rv_label -- text to show on site)
   )
   ```

While parsing query to your application, to every radio button add ra_id.
While saving result u get rv_id whitch represents selected value.

---

So now lets do a form table

```
CREATE TABLE Form (fa_id, fa_name)
CREATE TABLE FormControlls (fac_id, fa_id, fa_rg_id, fa_cb_id)
```

So finnaly you have a form with refers to checkboxes and radiogroup items.
In application you have to set rv_id to radiogroup variant and pass it to UserFormData.

```
CREATE TABLE UserFormData (ufd_id, ufd_fa_id, fa_rg_id, fa_rg_value --ID of selected variant,
fa_cb_id, fa_cb_value --state of checkbox)
```

Im late for meeting, but I belive u "catch" the theory.